# Dear Hans - the old letter

Tags: steganography, language

During one of your late-night studies at library you found a piece of paper, which was used as a bookmark. You opened it and read its content. It seemed to be one of these post-war letters that never reached its recipient. Can it hide something?

```
Dear Hans,

news are traveling fast. You must heard that finally all those nazi felons are getting caught. 
I think that after a few weeks they all will be given justice. Now lets talk about the most important matter.
Imagine that their leader committed suicide in his secret bunker. To me - it is laughable.
Not that I thought of him as brave man. You remember what I was telling you. 
Great man does not need to hurt others to be great. Real hero is the one who protects.
Always remember that.

Do what must be done. Certainly they deserved everything that will fall on them. Any other person will tell you the same thing.
No one from this nazi scums deserves the trail.

Don't you seek revenge? Otto agreed with me. 
Let him talk to you. Friends should discuss their actions together.

Remember what they did to you and your family. You are known from kind heart and forgiving nature.
Rather than following your usual path - show them true meaning of despair.
During our travels together you told me once that revenge is bad thing. Unfortunetly, this time I can't agree.
Friends forever.

Yours Erhard.
```

---

Small hint #1:

> Split of the text is important.

---

Medium hint #1:

> Otto may seem to be the most worth knowing at START, but later you will notice that the others are of KEY importance.

Medium hint #2:

> One particular nation thinks about themselves as the FIRST among races(two hints here).

---

Big hint #1:

> Hans and Erhard should be used with prefixes.

Big hint #2:

> After extraction of something - try looking at it from different perspective.

---

DESTROY THE FUN hint #1:

> Most of the text could be entirely random.

Comment: Since this is steganography, I'm assuming all the grammar and spelling errors are intentional?

Comment: I don't want to add hints too early. Let me know if they are necessary.

Comment: Oh, that's perfectly ok, no need to do anything. Sometimes we get first time posters that don't write English all that well, in which case we are glad to help; I'm guessing this isn't one of those cases :-)

Comment: Hints will be added - two small tonight and two medium tomorrow.

Comment: Edit 1: added small hints.

Comment: Edit 2: added medium hints. Next hint can be obtained only as a comment to answer. So, even if you are not sure or have only a partial solution - don't hesitate to publish it.

Comment: Edit 3: Reworked hints - puzzle is much more easier now. It should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I think it should work now. Working on the problem.

Comment: It’s been a while. More hints please?

Answer (score 1):

> Based on the hints and some research, I found that the writer is probably  Ludwig Erhard. The 'Otto' mentioned is probably Otto Ohlendorf. I am still  not sure of the hidden clue in the letter, but I'm wondering if it's      hinting at some  kind of planned fall of Hitler. Answer to small hint #2, 'Divide and conquer' is what they were planning? Got to think more. Great puzzle.

Comment: rot13(Gel sbphfvat yrff ba punenpgref. Gurl ner vzcbegnag sbe n fbyhgvba, abg n fgbel. Guvax ubj Fznyy uvag #2 pbhyq or nccyvrq gb gur grkg. Yrggre jnf jevggra nsgre Uvgyre'f snyy.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the question meant. But what I was able to derive was that..

It is related to **Nazi Germany**

This is a letter before

> June or July 1951. The aftermaths of WW2

And it's related to

> The 11 War Crimes and Nuremberg Execution

The guy who wrote the letter **Erhard**
His full name is

> Erhard Milch.

He is a

> Field Marshal who was very much involved in development of Luftwaffe(air forces of Nazi)

I am quite confused about the **Hans**, to whom the letter was addressed.

There are several(4-5) people who can be him.
Most Probably

> Hans Franck. He is a German Lawyer.

And the friend **Otto** that was mentioned most probably is

> Otto Ohlendorf. Indeed a very powerful man who responsible for Intelligence and Security of Nazi Germany.

-----OR------

> Otto Wöhler. He was a Army General.

I don't know whether I am right or not.

> I guess that this letter is a few weeks before the The Nuremberg Execution which executed those who were found guilty of commiting Crimes against Humanity. Somehow Erhard is trying to communicate to Hans to save them by establishing a communication with Otto.

`This is my first answer in Puzzling. Please help me improve my answers. And please do comments and give some more hints about the questions and what do we have to find.
Please let me know if there are any grammatical errors.`

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Feedback as requested: There are grammatical errors. Unless they cause confusion, errors in grammar are fine. You used the spoiler tags well enough. Other than that, it looks good. As for hints, that is entirely up to the person asking the question. That varies for each person. Have fun.

Comment: Thank You. I know it's not the right place to ask but  How am I supposed to edit my profile using app?

Comment: rot13(Gel sbphfvat yrff ba punenpgref. Gurl ner vzcbegnag sbe n fbyhgvba, abg n fgbel. Guvax ubj angvba lbh thrffrq pna or hfrq jvgu gntf. Lrf, Reuneq vf gelvat gb pbzzhavpngr jvgu Unaf naq gur zrffntr vf gur fbyhgvba.)

Comment: @user88566 Not sure. I use my PC for that stuff. It may not be a feature yet. I don't see any options other than email settings when on my mobile. Good thinking though. You should ask questions like that on META. :)

Comment: Vigenère(K EDM GQLP AQVV IAIVM WDN K EJXAA ZRL ZGCYIXL VF IAM IVPBTV WEGUBKIVZMC)

Comment: rot13(Cebivqr gur xrl be hfr ebg13.)

Comment: rot13(V tbg lbhe uvag.
Vf vg eryngrq gb Trezna Havsvpngvba?)

Comment: rot13(Ab. Lbh ner sbphfvat gbb zhpu ba onpxtebhaq naq fgbel. Guvax ubj uvagf pna or nccyvrq gb grkg.)

Comment: Ok. I will definitely try to follow your hints and advice.

Comment: Can you please give a final Hint in public. This problem is GREAT.